# Calculating Birthday Problem probabibilites for different number

Tags: probability, birthday

A fellow programmer I know is designing his system around a random ID per "active" user, however this ID only has 1 million different possibilities. Thinking of the Birthday Problem I thought to myself that this isn't very safe even with a small userbase at first.

I was wondering how I could calculate for a set of different possibilities (1 million in my case) how many users you could use before you get a percentage chance of collision? I have tried solving this programatically and I came up with about an average of 1250 users where the most collisions started appearing. I found some formulaes but they all seem to use giant factorials that my programs / calculators can't perform.

Is there any way to solve this with a single equation (instead of recursion), something like:

With `x` different unique ID's, you'd expect a `y`% chance of a collision at `n` users. (x and y being input)

Sorry if I'm using the wrong definitions, just a programmer with enthusiasm for math :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Wikipedia article says the number needed for $50\%$ chance of collision where there are $n$ possible days is about $\sqrt {2 \ln 2 n}$.  That has no large factorials in it.  It is about $1177$  To deal with large factorials, the standard approach is [Stirling's approximation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stirling%27s_approximation) $n! \approx (\frac ne)^n\sqrt {2 \pi n}$  It is quite accurate and if you take logs you avoid the big numbers.

Comment: So are these just for 50% or is it possible to get different percentages with the sqrt(2ln2n)?

Comment: You can adapt the $2 \ln2$ constant to give the percentage chance you want.  If you follow the article they put in $\frac 12$ on the left because they want the $50\%$ chance.  Plug in your favorite number and follow through.

Comment: Accepting this as an answer. So for example if I wanted to test for 33% chance I'd do sqrt($3ln3n$)? EDIT: Or do you mean 1/2 because squareroot is the same as to the power of 1/2 so ($2ln2n$)^1/3?

Comment: Ignore my previous comments, I understand now :)